# PHP Parse huge XML file

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML document like this, it's > 400 MB file.

My issue is that I cannot get XMLReader to not run into memory limit, have a 512 Mb PHP 7.2 server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetModifiedResponse xmlns="http://host.com">
<ProductList>
<UpdatedProducts>
  <ProductId>1</ProductId>
  <ProductId>2</ProductId>
  <ProductId>3</ProductId>
  <ProductId>4</ProductId>
</UpdatedProducts>
<RemovedProducts>
  <ProductId>5</ProductId>
  <ProductId>6</ProductId>
  <ProductId>7</ProductId>
  <ProductId>8</ProductId>
</RemovedProducts>
</ProductList>
..
```

This is kinda my script, and the issue here is that the whole "`UpdatedProducts`" is loaded and max the ram out. And need a similar for RemovedProducts, both need to be in the loop, how to solve the problem - if possible w.o. put more ram in the server (or `memory_limit(-1)`)?

```php
    while ($xml->name == 'UpdatedProducts') {
      $elm = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXml());

      foreach ($elm->ProductId as $product) {
        $this->saveToDb($product);
      }

      $xml->next('UpdatedProducts');
    }
```

### Update:

the code is right now

```
$xml = new \XMLReader();
    $xml->open(__DIR__ . '/../../var/tmp/out.xml');

    while ($xml->read()) {
      while ($xml->name == 'UpdatedProducts') {
      while ($xml->read() && $xml->name != 'ProductId');
        while ($xml->name == 'ProductId') {
          $this->saveToDb($xml->readInnerXml(), 'update');
          $xml->next('ProductId');
        }
        $xml->next('UpdatedProducts');
      }
      while ($xml->name == 'RemovedProducts') {
        while ($xml->read() && $xml->name != 'ProductId');
        while ($xml->name == 'ProductId') {
          $this->saveToDb($xml->readInnerXml(), 'remove');
          $xml->next('ProductId');
        }
        $xml->next('RemovedProducts');
      }
    }
```

Comment: So, does your script works with `memory_limit(-1)`?

Comment: You mention XMLReader but you're eventually using SimpleXML. The former should work fine with files any size—the latter won't.

Comment: $xml = new \XMLReader();
    $xml->open(__DIR__ . '/../../var/tmp/out.xml');

Comment: Aksen P, yes it works with memory_limit = -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using SimpleXML to fetch all of the nodes within `<UpdatedProducts>`, you could nest the same code to make it read inside this node for the ` nodes.  This will mean that the inner loop will get 1 node at a time...

```
while ($xml->name == 'UpdatedProducts') {
    while ($xml->read() && $xml->name !== 'ProductId');
    while ($xml->name == 'ProductId') {
        echo $xml->readOuterXml().PHP_EOL;
        $xml->next('ProductId');
    }
    $xml->next('UpdatedProducts');
}
```

For both of the types, I've tried to reduce it to one loop.  It's not ideal but seems to work...

```
$xml = new \XMLReader();
$xml->open(__DIR__ . '/../../var/tmp/out.xml');
while ($xml->read() && $xml->name != 'UpdatedProducts');
$type = "update";
while ($xml->read() && $xml->name != 'ProductId');
while ($xml->name == 'ProductId') {
    $id = $xml->readInnerXml();
    if ( !empty($id) )  {
        $this->saveToDb($xml->readInnerXml(), $type);
    }
    while ($xml->read() && $xml->name != 'ProductId'
            && $xml->name != 'RemovedProducts');
    if ( $xml->name == 'RemovedProducts' )  {
        $type = "remove";
        while ($xml->read() && $xml->name != 'ProductId');
    }
}
```

There is an alternative, using a library I've written to wrap around XMLReader (at https://github.com/NigelRel3/XMLReaderReg).  You will have to download it as there is no composer version yet.  But copy the XMLReaderReg.php script to your project and

```
require_once "XMLReaderReg.php";
```

then you can use...

```
$reader = new XMLReaderReg();
$reader->open(__DIR__ ."/../../var/tmp/out.xml");

$reader->process([
    '.*/UpdatedProducts/ProductId' => function (SimpleXMLElement $data): void {
        $this->saveToDb((string)$data, "update");
    },
    '.*/RemovedProducts/ProductId' => function (SimpleXMLElement $data): void {
        $this->saveToDb((string)$data, "remove");
    },
]);

$reader->close();
```

Comment: How can i iterate over both Updatedproducts and RemovedProducts in this ? Right now i have added the same code, but changed UpdatedProducts to RemovedProducts and loop that afterwards. And that ends up in a Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted